# как реализовать наклон камеры в openGL (вращать вверх, вниз)

Tags: android, opengl

Здравствуйте, я делаю 3d сцену на андроид. Мне нужно реализовать наклон камеры. 
Получается, что если угол вращения по Y = 0.  То за наклон верх-вниз, отвечает вращение по оси Х.
Если угол вращения по Y = 90. То за наклон верх-вниз, отвечает вращение по оси Z.

Вот я что-то попытался написать, но получается ерунда.

```
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
        //Clear Screen And Depth Buffer
        gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        gl.glLoadIdentity();                    //Reset The Current Modelview Matrix

        gl.glRotatef(azimut, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f); // вращение по оси Y 

//        float angle = roll;  //  угол наклона телефона
//        double angleRadianse = Math.toRadians(angle);
//        float angleCos = (float) Math.cos(angleRadianse);
//        float angleSin = (float) Math.sin(angleRadianse);
//        gl.glRotatef(angleSin * angle, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);  //X
//        gl.glRotatef(angleCos * angle , 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);  //Z

        iterPos = 0;
        while (iterPos < cubes.size()) {
            cubes.get(iterPos++).draw(gl);
        }
        gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    }
```

Как я могу реализовать наклон камеры?

Answer (score 1):

вроде разобрался.

```
float roll;
float azimut;

    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
        //Clear Screen And Depth Buffer
        gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        gl.glLoadIdentity();                    //Reset The Current Modelview Matrix

        gl.glRotatef(azimut, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f); //Y

        float angle = azimut;
        double angleRadianse = Math.toRadians(angle);
        float angleCos = (float) Math.cos(angleRadianse);
        float angleSin = (float) Math.sin(angleRadianse);

        gl.glRotatef(angleCos * roll , 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);  //X
        gl.glRotatef(angleSin * roll , 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);  //Z

        iterPos = 0;
        while (iterPos < cubes.size()) {
            cubes.get(iterPos++).draw(gl);
        }
        gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    }
```